# How to group this SQL outer join query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Currently I'm executing the following:

```
SELECT  SiteFeatures.SiteId, Blogs.FeatureInstance_Id as BlogId, 
        PageCollections.FeatureInstance_Id as PagesId, 
        Portfolios.FeatureInstance_Id as PortfolioId
FROM    SiteFeatures 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Blogs 
                ON SiteFeatures.FeatureInstanceId = Blogs.FeatureInstance_id 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Portfolios 
                ON SiteFeatures.FeatureInstanceId = Portfolios.FeatureInstance_id 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN PageCollections 
                ON SiteFeatures.FeatureInstanceId = PageCollections.FeatureInstance_id
```

This returns a result set like so:

```
SiteId      BlogId      PagesId     PortfolioId
1           1           NULL        NULL
1           NULL        1           NULL
1           NULL        NULL        1   
2           2           NULL        NULL
2           NULL        2           NULL
2           NULL        NULL        2
```

Which means I am having to aggregate these within my application code. How can I change my query (with performance in mind) to return:

```
SiteId      BlogId      PagesId     PortfolioId
1           1           1           1
1           2           2           2
```

As requested - my schema:

[image: dbdiagram]

Comment: Can you show your table structures and PK/Fk relationships?

Comment: Do you need to use LEFT OUTER JOINS?  Your example data seems to indicate otherwise.

Comment: With given query, I can't imagine for the life of me how to get your *initial* output. Are you sure the data you've given us is representative?

Comment: I can't even imagine it being a data issue... I don't see how that query, as given, can possibly return that resultset.

Comment: I've added my schema as requested. Perhaps my original query wasn't the best - my SQL is a little 'ahem rusty, to say the least...

Comment: Why does SiteFeatures.SiteId allow `null`s?

Comment: Well spotted @Johan, it shouldn't do. Db is generated by ORM and I had missed this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
   S.SiteId,
   B.FeatureInstance_Id BlogId, 
   P.FeatureInstance_Id PortfolioId,
   C.FeatureInstance_Id PagesId
FROM
   Sites S
   LEFT JOIN (
      SiteFeatures F1
      INNER JOIN Blogs B ON F1.FeatureInstanceId = B.FeatureInstance_id
   ) ON S.SiteID = F1.SiteID
   LEFT JOIN (
      SiteFeatures F2
      INNER JOIN Portfolios P ON F2.FeatureInstanceId = P.FeatureInstance_id
   ) ON S.SiteID = F2.SiteID
   LEFT JOIN (
      SiteFeatures F3
      LEFT JOIN PageCollections C ON F3.FeatureInstanceId = C.FeatureInstance_id
   ) ON S.SiteID = F3.SiteID
```

This should work okay assuming that all your child tables can only have one row for each `FeatureInstance_Id`.

If you designed the database, you've earned a good rap on the knuckles for having inconsistent column names among the tables. :)

If this query works then you might consider encapsulating this in a series of views which will return the query to a nice compact thing:

```
CREATE VIEW BlogsFeature
AS
SELECT
   F.*
FROM
   SiteFeatures F
   WHERE EXISTS ( -- or you could do an INNER JOIN, though in theory this is correct
      SELECT 1
      FROM Blogs B
      WHERE F.FeatureInstanceId = B.FeatureInstance_id
   )
```

Doing this for all three tables will yield the following query:

```
SELECT
   S.SiteId,
   B.FeatureInstance_Id BlogId, 
   P.FeatureInstance_Id PortfolioId,
   C.FeatureInstance_Id PagesId
FROM
   Sites S
   LEFT JOIN BlogsFeature B ON S.SiteID = B.SiteID
   LEFT JOIN PortfoliosFeature P ON S.SiteID = P.SiteID
   LEFT JOIN PageCollections C O ON S.SiteID = C.SiteID
```

Actually, this made me think of another way to express the query you need, though it's still not very pretty-looking:

```
SELECT
   S.SiteId,
   F1.FeatureInstance_Id BlogId, 
   F2.FeatureInstance_Id PortfolioId,
   F3.FeatureInstance_Id PagesId
FROM
   Sites S
   LEFT JOIN SiteFeatures F1
      ON S.SiteID = F1.SiteID
      AND EXISTS (
         SELECT 1 FROM Blogs B
         WHERE F1.FeatureInstanceId = B.FeatureInstance_id
      ) 
   LEFT JOIN SiteFeatures F2
      ON S.SiteID = F2.SiteID
      AND EXISTS (
         SELECT 1 FROM Portfolios P
         WHERE F2.FeatureInstanceId = P.FeatureInstance_id
      )
   LEFT JOIN SiteFeatures F3
      ON S.SiteID = F3.SiteID
      AND EXISTS (
         SELECT 1 FROM PageCollections C
         WHERE F3.FeatureInstanceId = C.FeatureInstance_id
      )
```

You could use the Max() idea still if you converted your uniqueidentifiers to strings temporarily.

```
SELECT
   S.SiteId,
   B.FeatureInstance_Id BlogId, 
   P.FeatureInstance_Id PortfolioId,
   C.FeatureInstance_Id PagesId
FROM
   SiteFeatures F
   INNER JOIN Blogs B ON
```

Comment: @Erik yes I know :) This is just a proof of concept and the schema has been generated by NHibernate. I'll fix up the column names correctly once we've finished these tests.

Comment: @Erik, this returned 54 records compared to the 6 on my original query.

Comment: @Erik - Had to change to "SELECT
   S.SiteId,
   F1.FeatureInstanceId BlogId, 
   F2.FeatureInstanceId PortfolioId,
   F3.FeatureInstanceId PagesId", but other than that, it works great. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Ben I presume you mean in my biggest EXISTS query? Fixed.

Comment: @Erik, yes sorry, should't have been more specific.

Comment: @Ben What does the execution plan look like?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT   SiteFeatures.SiteId
         , MAX(Blogs.FeatureInstance_Id) as BlogId
         , MAX(PageCollections.FeatureInstance_Id) as PagesId
         , MAX(Portfolios.FeatureInstance_Id) as PortfolioId
FROM     SiteFeatures 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Blogs 
         ON SiteFeatures.FeatureInstanceId = Blogs.FeatureInstance_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Portfolios 
         ON SiteFeatures.FeatureInstanceId = Portfolios.FeatureInstance_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PageCollections 
         ON SiteFeatures.FeatureInstanceId = PageCollections.FeatureInstance_id
GROUP BY SiteFeatures.SiteId
ORDER BY SiteFeatures.SiteId ASC
```

Comment: thanks for this. Unfortunately this won't work for me as my Id columns are unique identifiers (max won't work). This is my fault, I should have included more details about my schema. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `INNER JOIN`s and not `LEFT JOIN`s ?

```
SELECT  SiteFeatures.SiteId
      , Blogs.FeatureInstance_Id as BlogId 
      , PageCollections.FeatureInstance_Id as PagesId 
      , Portfolios.FeatureInstance_Id as PortfolioId
FROM  SiteFeatures 
          INNER JOIN Blogs 
              ON SiteFeatures.FeatureInstanceId = Blogs.FeatureInstance_id 
          INNER JOIN Portfolios 
              ON SiteFeatures.FeatureInstanceId = Portfolios.FeatureInstance_id 
          INNER JOIN PageCollections 
              ON SiteFeatures.FeatureInstanceId = PageCollections.FeatureInstance_id
```

On second thought, this may be what you want:

```
SELECT  sf.SiteId
      , ( SELECT b.FeatureInstance_Id 
          FROM Blogs AS b
          WHERE sf.FeatureInstanceId = b.FeatureInstance_id
        )  AS BlogId 
      , ( SELECT pc.FeatureInstance_Id 
          FROM PageCollections AS pc
          WHERE sf.FeatureInstanceId = pc.FeatureInstance_id
        )  AS PagesId 
      , ( SELECT p.FeatureInstance_Id 
          FROM Portfolios  AS p
          WHERE sf.FeatureInstanceId = p.FeatureInstance_id
        )  AS PortfolioId
FROM  SiteFeatures  AS sf
```

---

On third thought (and after seeing Eric's answer that got accepted), I'll make one more try, just to show that it can be done with (this kind of) subqueries:

```
SELECT  s.SiteId
      , ( SELECT b.FeatureInstance_Id 
          FROM Blogs AS b
            JOIN SiteFeatures sf
              ON sf.FeatureInstanceId = b.FeatureInstance_id
          WHERE sf.SiteId = s.SiteId
        )  AS BlogId 
      , ( SELECT pc.FeatureInstance_Id 
          FROM PageCollections AS pc
            JOIN SiteFeatures sf
              ON sf.FeatureInstanceId = pc.FeatureInstance_id
          WHERE sf.SiteId = s.SiteId
        )  AS PagesId 
      , ( SELECT p.FeatureInstance_Id 
          FROM Portfolios  AS p
            JOIN SiteFeatures sf
              ON sf.FeatureInstanceId = p.FeatureInstance_id
          WHERE sf.SiteId = s.SiteId
        )  AS PortfolioId
FROM  Sites  AS s
```

Comment: @ypercube - first query doesn't return any results. A site has many features but a feature only has a Blog OR Portfolio OR PageCollection. The second query just returns the same as what my original posted query returns.

Comment: @Ben: OK, then @Eric's answer seems what you want. (with INNER JOINs instead of LEFT JOINs)

Comment: @ypercube - I'm not so sure (see my comment on @Erik's answer). Gives me far more results than I had originally.

Comment: @Ben he's right, I needed the INNER JOINs. @ypercube, your updated query still won't work as the `SiteFeatures` table has one row for every Site Feature, including the ones that aren't correct for the current row. You have to take it up a step to SiteID.

Comment: @Eric, you are right. I was not thinking correctly. It's very well normalized database (for a complex relation) and I guess I'm too used working with denormalized tables regarding such cases.

Answer (score 1):

Since your are using `SQL Server 2008`, here is one possible option using **CROSS APPLY** that might work for you. It may not be the best looking option here. I just gave it a shot.

```
SELECT          SFR.SiteId
            ,   BLG.FeatureInstance_Id  AS BlogId
            ,   PFL.FeatureInstance_Id  AS PortfolioId
            ,   PGC.FeatureInstance_Id  AS PagesId
FROM            dbo.SiteFeatures    SFR
CROSS APPLY     (
                    SELECT 
                    TOP 1   FeatureInstance_Id
                    FROM    dbo.Blogs BLG
                    WHERE   BLG.FeatureInstance_Id  = SFR.FeatureInstanceId
                ) BLG
CROSS APPLY     (
                    SELECT 
                    TOP 1   FeatureInstance_Id
                    FROM    dbo.PortFolios PFL
                    WHERE   PFL.FeatureInstance_Id  = SFR.FeatureInstanceId
                ) PFL
CROSS APPLY     (
                    SELECT 
                    TOP 1   FeatureInstance_Id
                    FROM    dbo.PageCollections PGC
                    WHERE   PGC.FeatureInstance_Id  = SFR.FeatureInstanceId
                ) PGC
```

Comment: interesting. This doesn't return any results (it does if only CROSS APPLY to BLG) but I'll give CROSS APPLY a go tomorrow.

Comment: that works. But gives me exactly the same as my original query :) Perhaps I should carry on doing aggregation within my application...